# BitmapFactory.decodeFile() returns null when file exists in internal memory

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I have the following jpg image in the internal memory, but `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` returns `null`:

[image]

```
   File imgFile = new  File("/data/user/0/com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.test/files/t.jpg");
   // same result for `File imgFile = new  File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "t.jpg");`
   Bitmap bitmap = null;
   if(imgFile.exists()){
      BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
      bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions); // null
   }
```

It can detect that `imgFile` exists, but the return value is null. Does anyone know what might be the reason?

Comment: Why are you using a full path?  Especially that path, which doesn't look right (why is there a user/0/ in there?  Unless you have an unusual device that's not where an app's data is put)?  In Android you should NEVER hardcode a path, you should use Enviornment functions for the base path and provide a relative path to that.

Comment: That's the value I get from `getContext().getFilesDir()` for the emulator, but the path is valid because `imgFile.exists()` returns true.  I've tried `File imgFile = new  File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "t.jpg");` as well, but I get the same result.

Comment: Do you have read access to it?  Just existing isn't enough.  And if you do, try putting the image into res and see if you can load it there.  If not, the problem is the file itself.

Comment: @GabeSechan Isn't internal storage always accessible to the app? I've put it in `assets` and it loads fine.

Comment: Internal app storage yes.  But that's not the right path.  My guess is it's due to getContext not being the right context-  if this is an espresso test app, the test app is a different app than the app being tested, and doesn't have access to the tested app's files.

Comment: If you want to double check that's the problem-  just try to open a FileInputStream for that file and see what exception it throws.

Comment: @GabeSechan Oh! I get permission denied. I wonder what causes it. Could the path really be the wrong path? No, it's no an espresso test app.

Comment: How did the file get there in the first place?

Comment: @GabeSechan I just uploaded it into the emulator. It has file permissions -rw-rw-rw.

Comment: If you uploaded it to the emulator, it isn't going to be owned by the right app.  That could be the problem.  Although with 666 permission that should be ok.

Comment: @GabeSechan You're right! Once I created the file using the app and stored it in the same dir, it works fine. Thank you!